# JS Check for holidays

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have call center and I use this JS code to let messages come in during business hours and after business hours/weekends it display a message saying that is outside of support time, my question is, how I make this code work also for holidays?

```
exports.handler = async function(context, event, callback) {
  const moment = require('moment-timezone');
  var now = moment().tz('America/New_York');
  console.log('Current time-->'+now);
  console.log('current hours-->'+now.hour());
  
  let isWorkingHours = false;
  //let isWorkingHours = true; // testing
 
  const weekday = now.isoWeekday(); 
  console.log('weekday-->'+weekday);
  
  if (now.hour() >= 9 && now.hour() <= 17 && weekday <= 5) {
  //if (now.hour() >= 4 && now.hour() <= 20 && weekday <= 2) { // testing
      isWorkingHours = true;
      //Console.log('This is outside working hours');
    }
    callback(null, {
    isWorkingHours: isWorkingHours
    });
}
```

Comment: Seems pretty straightforward. Make a list of holidays and check to see if your date is in  that list. Have you tried that? Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: I think the OP is referring to holidays that do not have a static date: Easter for example changes its date based on the moon phase. Based on the office country we might be able to code something that checks it, but until we don't know it we can't code much

Comment: This needs to define "holiday" as in "bank holiday", Some country holiday? Some context defined holiday set like company observed holidays (maybe the founders birthday is a holiday somewhere for example)

Answer (score 0):

I got this holiday checker from someone else's post here on StackOverflow (I should have documented the link, but I forgot to). You can iterate through all the dates you are interested in to create a complete list of holidays, or just check if a given date is a holiday

```
function check_holiday (dt_date) {

    // check simple dates (month/date - no leading zeroes)
    var n_date = dt_date.getDate(),
        n_month = dt_date.getMonth() + 1;
    var s_date1 = n_month + '/' + n_date;
    
    if (   s_date1 == '1/1'   // New Year's Day
        || s_date1 == '6/14'  // Flag Day
        || s_date1 == '7/4'   // Independence Day
        || s_date1 == '11/11' // Veterans Day
        || s_date1 == '12/25' // Christmas Day
    ) return true;
    
    // weekday from beginning of the month (month/num/day)
    var n_wday = dt_date.getDay(),
        n_wnum = Math.floor((n_date - 1) / 7) + 1;
    var s_date2 = n_month + '/' + n_wnum + '/' + n_wday;
    
    if (   s_date2 == '1/3/1'  // Birthday of Martin Luther King, third Monday in January
        || s_date2 == '2/3/1'  // Washington's Birthday, third Monday in February
        || s_date2 == '5/3/6'  // Armed Forces Day, third Saturday in May
        || s_date2 == '9/1/1'  // Labor Day, first Monday in September
        || s_date2 == '10/2/1' // Columbus Day, second Monday in October
        || s_date2 == '11/4/4' // Thanksgiving Day, fourth Thursday in November
    ) return true;

    // weekday number from end of the month (month/num/day)
    var dt_temp = new Date (dt_date);
    dt_temp.setDate(1);
    dt_temp.setMonth(dt_temp.getMonth() + 1);
    dt_temp.setDate(dt_temp.getDate() - 1);
    n_wnum = Math.floor((dt_temp.getDate() - n_date - 1) / 7) + 1;
    var s_date3 = n_month + '/' + n_wnum + '/' + n_wday;
    
    if (   s_date3 == '5/1/1'  // Memorial Day, last Monday in May
    ) return true;

    // misc complex dates
    if (s_date1 == '1/20' && (((dt_date.getFullYear() - 1937) % 4) == 0) 
    // Inauguration Day, January 20th every four years, starting in 1937. 
    ) return true;
        
    if (n_month == 11 && n_date >= 2 && n_date < 9 && n_wday == 2
    // Election Day, Tuesday on or after November 2. 
    ) return true;
    
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I find it dirty to have these holidays hardcoded. It would be better some sort of cache or repository where to store them (also it would enable more possibilities, like add non-holidays that are days off)

Answer (score 0):

The logic for checking if an specific instant in time is outside working ours is in your if statement.

I would abstract this in some sort of storage, based on time ranges for holidays or any day off. You could either have a table or cache where to store these holidays (you should load them in advance).

That way, you can do something like:

1. Search if there's a holiday whose date matches with the current date (matching just date without timestamp, you can use moment's [isSame](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/) checking just by date)
2. If there's a match, return isWorkingHours as false

To check if the date matches, you can use this (regardless of current time, it returns true as you're comparing at date level):

```
console.log(moment('2021-05-10 14:00:00').isSame('2021-05-10', 'day'));
```

Comment: The developers of Moment.js [don't even recommend using Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/) anymore. There are better, smaller options available, like [ProtoDate.js](https://github.com/Pamblam/protodate#readme).

Comment: I put the example using moment since the OP is using moment, and I don't know if he plans to replace it or not. If he decides to change it, then he just needs to search for an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a list of things that you might want to check for:

- Weekends
- "Static date" holidays (eg: Christmas)
- "Variable date" holidays (eg: Easter)
- Times (eg: your office opens at 8:00)

```
/* Function that checks if office is available at a specific date
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function is_office_available (date = new Date()) {

  // weekends, or actually any other day of the week
  let day = date.getDay();
  if ( [0 /*sunday*/, 6 /*saturday*/].includes(day) ) return false;

  // "static date" holidays (formatted as 'DD/MM')
  let dd_mm = date.getDate() + '/' + (date.getMonth()+1);
  if ( ['24/12', '25/12'].includes(dd_mm) ) return false;

  // TODO: "variable date" holidays

  // specific times
  // this logic has to be extended a LOT if, for example, you have
  // the office open from 8:30 to 17:30 with a launch break from 12:00 to 13:00 on weekdays
  // and from 9:00 to 12:00 only on mondays
  let hh = date.getHours();
  if (9 < hh || hh > 17) return false;
  

  // if no test returned true then the office is going to be available on that date
  return true;

}
```

You can simply call this function in an if statement.

"Variable date" holidays have a quite a long (and boring) implementation to do and it depends on the ones you have in your country office.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I check for US Holidays whenever I need to mess around with Dates & Times.

First I create a `getToday()` function that all the other functions derive from. This makes it dynamic based on the current Day I am in. It's Little heavy on code comments to make sure I explain the logic in each function.

I've tested all 11 functions including leap year support. Hope this helps.

```js
function getToday() {
  return new Date();
}
// 1. New Year's Day - January 1st
function getNewYearsDay(today) {
  const year = today.getFullYear();
  return new Date(year, 0, 1); // January is month 0 in JavaScript
}
// 2. Martin Luther King Jr. Day - Third Monday in January
function getThirdMondayInJanuary(today) {
  const year = today.getFullYear();
  const januaryFirst = new Date(year, 0, 1); // January is month 0 in JavaScript
  let dayOfWeek = januaryFirst.getDay(); // 0 is Sunday, 1 is Monday, etc.
  // Calculate how many days to add to get to the first Monday in January
  // If January 1st is a Monday (1), add 7, otherwise calculate the difference to the next Monday
  const daysToAdd = dayOfWeek === 1 ? 7 : (8 - dayOfWeek);
  // Calculate the third Monday
  const thirdMonday = new Date(year, 0, 1 + daysToAdd + 7); // Add 7 more days for the third Monday
  return thirdMonday;
}
// 3. Presidents' Day - Third Monday in February
function getThirdMondayInFebruary(today) {
  const year = today.getFullYear();
  const februaryFirst = new Date(year, 1, 1); // February is month 1 in JavaScript
  let dayOfWeek = februaryFirst.getDay(); // 0 is Sunday, 1 is Monday, etc.
  // Calculate how many days to add to get to the first Monday in February
  // If February 1st is a Monday (1), add 14 (two weeks), otherwise calculate the difference to the next Monday and add 14
  const daysToAdd = dayOfWeek === 1 ? 14 : (8 - dayOfWeek) + 14;
  // Calculate the third Monday
  const thirdMonday = new Date(year, 1, 1 + daysToAdd);
  return thirdMonday;
}
// 4. Memorial Day - Last Monday in May
function getLastMondayInMay(today) {
  const year = today.getFullYear();
  const mayThirtyFirst = new Date(year, 4, 31); // May is month 4 in JavaScript
  let dayOfWeek = mayThirtyFirst.getDay(); // 0 is Sunday, 1 is Monday, etc.
  // Calculate how many days to subtract to get to the last Monday in May
  // If May 31st is a Monday (1), subtract 0, otherwise calculate the difference to the previous Monday
  const daysToSubtract = dayOfWeek === 1 ? 0 : dayOfWeek - 1;
  // Calculate the last Monday
  const lastMonday = new Date(year, 4, 31 - daysToSubtract);
  return lastMonday;
}
// 5. Juneteenth - June 19th
function getJuneteenth(today) {
  const year = today.getFullYear();
  return new Date(year, 5, 19); // June is month 5 in JavaScript
}
// 6. Independence Day - July 4th
function getIndependenceDay(today) {
  const year = today.getFullYear();
  return new Date(year, 6, 4); // July is month 6 in JavaScript
}
// 6.1 Independence Day - Observed
function getIndependenceDayObserved(today) {
  const year = today.getFullYear();
  const independenceDay = new Date(year, 6, 4); // July is month 6 in JavaScript
  const dayOfWeek = independenceDay.getDay(); // 0 is Sunday, 1 is Monday, etc.
  // If Independence Day falls on a Saturday, observe on Friday (July 3)
  if (dayOfWeek === 6) return new Date(year, 6, 3);
  // If Independence Day falls on a Sunday, observe on Monday (July 5)
  if (dayOfWeek === 0) return new Date(year, 6, 5);
  // Otherwise, return Independence Day on July 4
  return independenceDay;
}
// 7. Labor Day - First Monday in September
function getFirstMondayInSeptember(today) {
  const year = today.getFullYear();
  const septemberFirst = new Date(year, 8, 1); // September is month 8 in JavaScript
  let dayOfWeek = septemberFirst.getDay(); // 0 is Sunday, 1 is Monday, etc.
  // Calculate how many days to add to get to the first Monday in September
  // If September 1st is already a Monday (1), add 0 days, otherwise calculate the difference to the next Monday
  const daysToAdd = dayOfWeek === 1 ? 0 : (8 - dayOfWeek) % 7;
  // Calculate the first Monday
  const firstMonday = new Date(year, 8, 1 + daysToAdd);
  return firstMonday;
}
// 8. Columbus Day - Second Monday in October
function getSecondMondayInOctober(today) {
  const year = today.getFullYear();
  const octoberFirst = new Date(year, 9, 1); // October is month 9 in JavaScript
  let dayOfWeek = octoberFirst.getDay(); // 0 is Sunday, 1 is Monday, etc.
  // Calculate how many days to add to get to the first Monday in October
  // If October 1st is a Monday (1), add 7 days, otherwise calculate the difference to the next Monday
  const daysToAdd = dayOfWeek === 1 ? 7 : (8 - dayOfWeek);
  // Calculate the second Monday
  const secondMonday = new Date(year, 9, 1 + daysToAdd);
  return secondMonday;
}
// 9. Veterans Day - November 11th
function getVeteransDay(today) {
  const year = today.getFullYear();
  return new Date(year, 10, 11); // November is month 10 in JavaScript
}
// 9.1 Veterans Day - Observed
function getVeteransDayObserved(today) {
  const year = today.getFullYear();
  const veteransDay = new Date(year, 10, 11); // November is month 10 in JavaScript
  const dayOfWeek = veteransDay.getDay(); // 0 is Sunday, 1 is Monday, etc.
  // If Veterans Day falls on a Saturday, observe on Friday (November 10)
  if (dayOfWeek === 6) return new Date(year, 10, 10);
  // If Veterans Day falls on a Sunday, observe on Monday (November 12)
  if (dayOfWeek === 0) return new Date(year, 10, 12);
  // Otherwise, return Veterans Day on November 11
  return veteransDay;
}
// 10. Thanksgiving Day - Fourth Thursday in November
function getFourthThursdayInNovember(today) {
  const year = today.getFullYear();
  const novemberFirst = new Date(year, 10, 1); // November is month 10 in JavaScript
  let dayOfWeek = novemberFirst.getDay(); // 0 is Sunday, 1 is Monday, etc.
  // Calculate how many days to add to get to the first Thursday in November
  // If November 1st is a Thursday (4), add 0, otherwise calculate the difference to the next Thursday
  const daysToAdd = dayOfWeek === 4 ? 0 : (11 - dayOfWeek) % 7;
  // Calculate the fourth Thursday
  const fourthThursday = new Date(year, 10, 1 + daysToAdd + 21);
  return fourthThursday;
}
// 11. Christmas Day - December 25th
function getChristmasDay(today) {
  const year = today.getFullYear();
  return new Date(year, 11, 25); // December is month 11 in JavaScript
}

// Example usage
const today = getToday();

console.log("Today is:", today.toLocaleDateString());
console.log("New Year's Day:", getNewYearsDay(today).toLocaleDateString());
console.log("Martin Luther King Jr. Day:", getThirdMondayInJanuary(today).toLocaleDateString());
console.log("Presidents' Day:", getThirdMondayInFebruary(today).toLocaleDateString());
console.log("Memorial Day:", getLastMondayInMay(today).toLocaleDateString());
console.log("Juneteenth:", getJuneteenth(today).toLocaleDateString());
console.log("Independence Day:", getIndependenceDay(today).toLocaleDateString());
console.log("Independence Day Observed:", getIndependenceDayObserved(today).toLocaleDateString());
console.log("Labor Day:", getFirstMondayInSeptember(today).toLocaleDateString());
console.log("Columbus Day:", getSecondMondayInOctober(today).toLocaleDateString());
console.log("Veterans Day:", getVeteransDay(today).toLocaleDateString());
console.log("Veterans Day Observed:", getVeteransDayObserved(today).toLocaleDateString());
console.log("Thanksgiving Day:", getFourthThursdayInNovember(today).toLocaleDateString());
console.log("Christmas Day:", getChristmasDay(today).toLocaleDateString());
```